# How to auto increment by group in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, auto-increment

I have a data set with different categories
i.e.

```
customer_id category
a blue
b blue
c green
d green
e green
f pink
g pink
```

I'd like to insert into a DB2 table that auto increments a key for each category based on the order I inserted it i.e.

```
customer_id category auto_incr
a blue 1
b blue 2
c green 1
d green 2
e green 3
f pink 1
g pink 2
```

Then tomorrow when I have this new data set:

```
customer_id category auto_incr
h blue
i blue
j pink
```

My final dataset looks like:

```
customer_id category auto_incr
a blue 1
b blue 2
c green 1
d green 2
e green 3
f pink 1
g pink 2
h blue 3
i blue 4
j pink 3
```

I need to do this using DB2 sql and will be inserting into this table more than once

Comment: it will work well with a trigger. Try it, it is really easy. Tell us where you are stuck

Comment: i've never used a trigger before - have you got good examples?

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need to store these values in the table, because you can derive them on the fly:

```
SELECT 
 customer_id 
 ,category 
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY customer_id) AS auto_incr
FROM
 yourtable
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: how can this work when I need to insert into the table each day? and i'm not storing the number?